# Class isn't being added to current page? (want to highlight the active page)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to add a class to the current page the user is on in Wordpress..

So far i have the code below but it's not working does anyone know why?

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"> 
  <div id="grid-icon" class="icon-news<?php if (is_page($post->ID)) { 
  echo "page-active "; } else {} ?> col-xs-12 col-md-4">
     <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-short-title', true); ?></p>
  </div> </a>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: review :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/34897335/2667307

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line:

```
<div id="grid-icon" class="icon-news<?php if (is_page($post->ID)) { 
    echo "page-active "; } else {} ?> col-xs-12 col-md-4">
```

There isn't a space between the classes `icon-news` and `page-active`. Try changing the `echo` command to:

```
echo " page-active "; //note the space between `"` and `page-active`
```

---

This could also be abridged to:

```
<div id="grid-icon"
    class="icon-news<?php echo is_page($post->ID) ? " page-active " : null ?> col-xs-12 col-md-4">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add class using php code at that time you have to add a space initially before the class.

```
echo "page-active "; } else {} ?> col-xs-12 col-md-4">
```

line would be

```
echo " page-active "; } else {} ?> col-xs-12 col-md-4">
```